# Temperature converter that converts temp into Celsius, Fahrenheit and Kelvin using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a program that converts temperature into Celsius, Fahrenheit and Kelvin by taking a valid input from the user which provides the converted temp respectively using if, elif, else.
I just started learning tkinter so got no much idea about it, Kindly help me correct the source code.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("250x170") 
root.title('Temperature Converter')
frame=tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
l=tk.Label(root, text = "HELLO!!! Welcome to Temperature Converter") 
l.config(font =("Courier", 14)) 
l.pack()
t="Enter 1 To Convert Temperature Into Celsius.""\n"+"Enter 2 To Convert Temperature Into Fahrenheit.""\n"+"Enter 3 To Convert Temperature Into Kelvin."
l1=tk.Label(root, text = t,justify="left")
l1.config(font =("Courier", 14)) 
l1.pack(side="top",anchor="nw")  
def printtext():
    global e
    string = e.get() 
    print(string)  
e = tk.Entry(root,font =("Courier", 14))
e.pack(ipady=3,ipadx=3,anchor="center")
e.focus_set()

b = tk.Button(root,text='okay',font =("Courier", 13),command=printtext,anchor="center")
b.pack(side='top')
def Celsius():
    Fah=float(raw_input('Enter the temp in Fahrenheit')
    Celsius=(get(Fah)-32.0)*5.0//9.0)
    clabel=tk.Label(root,Celsius,text="Successfully Converted into Celsius")
    clabel.pack()
def Fahrenheit():
    Cel=float(raw_input('Enter the temp in Celsius')
    Fahrenheit=(get(Cel)*9.0//5.0+32)
    Flabel=tk.Label(root,Cel,text="Successfully Converted into Fahrenheit")
    Flabel.pack()
def Kelvin():
    Ces=float(raw_input('Enter the temp in Celsius')
    Kelvin=(get(Ces)+273)
    Klabel=tk.Label(root,Cel,text="Successfully Converted into Kelvin")
    Klabel.pack()  
def on_button():
    if e.get() == 1:
        Celsius()
    elif e.get() == 2:
        Fahrenheit()
    elif e.get() == 3:
        Kelvin()
    else: 
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title=None, message= "Invalid Choice")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how SO works. "Kindly help me correct the source code." is not a good question. To learn how tkinter works you can watch a tutorial on it. After you have made an attempt to solve the problem, you can ask a specific question.

Comment: @PythonicOreo  I am new to stackoverflow and so I apologize for the bad question. I did watch many tutorials but it didn't help much.

Comment: You still have not mentioned your problem.

Comment: If you using Tkinter you should be using a widget e.g. an Entry widget, to get input from the user.

Comment: @CoolCloud I have given 3 options as 1,2,3 for converting temp into celsius, fahrenheit and kelvin respectively, if the user gives value as 1 in the Entry widget, using if statement it should give temp in celsius which I have defined. I couldn't use the if statement correctly I guess... Please help...

Comment: @norie I have used the Entry widget to get input from the user. I want it to give temp in celsius if user selects 1, temp in Fahrenheit if user selects 2 and in kelvin if 3 is selected. Please do help me..

Comment: Why are you usng `raw_input()`, are you using python 2.x? If then, why is your tkinter import `from tkinter import *` it should `from Tkinter import *`

Comment: Start by arranging the code properly, then defining the functions and associating them with buttons. I could show you an example with a simple temperature converter if you like so.

Comment: @CoolCloud I use python 3.6.5, from tkinter import * tried that already but it sometimes shows an error .

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, Please give me an example...

Comment: `raw_input` is for python 2.x version, use `input()`.

Comment: There could be 9 `if` statements to be used for your case. Try google to get some temperature converter and follow tkinter tutorials.

Comment: @anagha I don't see any Entry widgets in the code you posted.

Comment: @norie `e=tk.Entry(...)`.

Comment: Apologies, didn't see that - but I would expect to see an Entry widget to enter the value to be converted.

Comment: @norie its solved, Anyway thank you so much.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written up some code, but what matters is that you try to understand it maximum. I have used radiobuttons to find out which is the main temperature and which is the converting temperature. I have used radiobutton, you can use `Combobox` too. Anyway, I have used a function and then chose to convert all the other values to it, and then to the desired values. Take a look:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

lhs = IntVar(value=-1)
rhs = IntVar(value=-1)
opt = ['Celcius','Farenheit','Kelvin']

def convert(temp,from_='K',to='C'):
    if from_ == to: return None
    
    from_k_formulas = {'C':lambda t: t-273.15,'F': lambda t: (t-273.15)*(9/5)+32,'K': lambda t:t}
    to_k_formulas   = {'C':lambda t: t+273.15,'F': lambda t: (t-32)*(5/9)+273.15,'K': lambda t:t}

    return from_k_formulas[to](to_k_formulas[from_](temp))

def process():
    from_ = opt[lhs.get()].upper()[0]
    to    = opt[rhs.get()].upper()[0]
    temp  = int(e.get())

    out   = convert(temp,from_,to)
    if out is not None:
        print(out)
    else:
        print('Choose distinct units')

Label(root,text='From').grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(root,text='To').grid(row=0,column=1)

for idx,txt in enumerate(opt): # To add first 3 radiobuttons
    Radiobutton(root,text=txt,variable=lhs,value=idx).grid(row=idx+1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

for idx,txt in enumerate(opt): # To add second 3 radiobuttons
    Radiobutton(root,text=txt,variable=rhs,value=idx).grid(row=idx+1,column=1,padx=10)

e = Entry(root)
e.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2)

Button(root,text='Convert',command=process).grid(row=5,column=0,pady=10,columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Here `lhs` is used to find the left side temperature and `rhs` is used to find the right side temperatures. And it returns the number of option selected, so then I index the list later with the returned number.

Comment: How to display the converted values??

Comment: I am using `print()`. You can store it inside a variable.

Comment: @anagha I have updated this answer with a better logic that I just learned. It seems too much work to use 9 `if` and then index it later. Here it gives you the answer with 0 `if`.