# Tkinter variable is not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Everything is working fine except when the program is loaded, I type in a number and try to convert using the button. The issue is that when the button is pressed, it always shows "converted temperature is: 0"

I believe that the variable "var" or the variable "number" is not updating. I am new to tkinter and struggling to figure out why the 0 is not being replaced with the correct temperature.

```
from tkinter import*

global number
global var
global textbox
number = 0
def convert():
    if var.get() == 1:
        number = float(textbox.get()) * 1.8 + 32
        return number
    elif var.get() == 2:
        number = (float(textbox.get()) - 32) / 1.8
        return number

main = Tk()
var = IntVar()
main.geometry("300x200")
main.configure(bg = 'black')
title = Label(main, text = "Temperature Converter", bg = 'black', fg = 'white' )
textbox = Entry(main, width = 8)
choice1 = Radiobutton(main, selectcolor = 'black', bg = 'black', fg = 'white', text = "Cel - Far", variable=var, value = 1)
choice2 = Radiobutton(main, selectcolor = 'black', bg = 'black', fg = 'white', text = 'Far - Cel', variable=var, value = 2)
button = Button(main, text = 'Convert', command = convert)
answer = Label(main, text = "Converted Temperature is: " + str(number), bg = 'black', fg = 'white' )

title.pack()
textbox.pack()
choice1.pack()
choice2.pack()
button.pack()
answer.pack()
main.resizable(False, False)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: `global` statements have no effect when they're outside a function.

Comment: The `convert()` function never updates `answer.text`.

Comment: If you are interested, look here to: [Temperature converter that converts temp into Celsius, Fahrenheit and Kelvin using Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66613207/13382000)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `convert` function to:

```py
def convert():
    if var.get() == 1:
        number = float(textbox.get()) * 1.8 + 32
    elif var.get() == 2:
        number = (float(textbox.get()) - 32) / 1.8
    answer.config(text="Converted Temperature is: " + str(number))
```

The `.config(...)` method changes the label. In this case it changes its `text` attribute.